# Javascript function expression typeof undefined

Tags: javascript, function, expression, undefined, typeof

Below is from MDN "Function Expression". Shouldn't `typeof baz` be `function`, not `undefined`? Why is `bar === baz` false?

```js
var foo = function() {}
foo.name // "foo"

var foo2 = foo
foo2.name // "foo"

var bar = function baz() {}
bar.name // "baz"

console.log(foo === foo2); // true
console.log(typeof baz); // undefined
console.log(bar === baz); // false (errors because baz == undefined)
```

Comment: `baz` is the name of the function (Google "Named function") but on the function itself.

Comment: The scope of the name in a named function expression is just the function body.

Answer (score 0):

You’re mixing function declaration styles.

If there’s a var, the line will get interpreted at runtime. If it’s `function name()` it will get interpreted at compile time.

If you mix it, you’ll get the function expression (hoisting) instead of the function declaration. And so you get bar instead of baz